# How to solve "Echo is not defined" error?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I am working with Laravel 7 with Vue.js and Laravel-echo.
I already installed the Laravel Echo library using `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js` in my application and also included the following code in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file as per the laravel provide documentation and also i have `require('./bootstrap');` in app.js and `script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` in app.blade.php.
But i am receiving the below error:

[image]

bootstrap.js:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});
```

show.blade.php

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
          comments: {},
          commentBox: '',
          post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
          user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : null !!}
      },
      created: function() {
        this.listen();
      },
      methods: {
        listen: function() {
          Echo.channel('post.'+this.post.id)
            .listen('NewComment', (comment) => {
              // this.comments.unshift(comment);
              console.log('yessss');
            })
        }
      }
    });
   </script>
```

Event: NewComment.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;  //for queueing 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;  //for no queueing 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Comment;

class NewComment implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $comment;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('post.'.$this->comment->post->id);
    }
}
```

.env:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=xxx

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I tried to remove forceTLS: true but still not working. I tried to add window.Echo but i received other error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined"

Any Solution for this Error?! Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Do you run `npm run watch`?

Comment: @kerbholz yes for sure!

Comment: Did you try `window.Echo.channel`?

Comment: yes and i received: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined @Purgatory

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command and try to clear cache files

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```